# How to solve simultaneous equations with both of the equations being quadratic equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I'm familiar with how to solve simultaneous equations with 1 quadratic equation but not 2. I've looked all of the internet for a thread that has covered this, but I can't seem to find one.
$$
\begin{cases}
(x+y)^2 = 1\\
\\
(3x+2y)(x-y) = -5
\end{cases}
$$
Could someone please describe the process?

Comment: Neither of these are equations.

Comment: My bad, accidentally forgot to add RHS.

Comment: @HenryPage, Is it not $$3x+2y?$$

Comment: Equation $1$ implies that $y=-x\pm1$ plug that into equation $2$ and solve for four values of $x$ and hence eight values of $y$ by using $y=-x\pm1$.

Comment: my bad, again. yes it is

Comment: This is exactly what I did, however, when I end up checking it, I get a completely different answer like (-15)(-5) = -5 which is not accurate.

Comment: You did not add that context to your question. Perhaps you just made an arithmetic error in your calculations?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, turned out just to be a calculation error from my side.

Comment: Your equation will simplify a lot by the transformation $$u = x+y\text{, }v = x-y$$ with the back-transform $$x = \frac{u+v}{2} \text{, } y =  \frac{u-v}{2}$$.

Comment: @Peter, each of the four values of $x$ comes from either $y=-1+x$ or $y=-1-x$, not both, so $y$ is fixed once $x$ is.

Comment: @Empy2 You are right. I can't edit the comment anymore so I guess I'll just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

What if $x=0$

Else set $y=mx$ to find $$\dfrac1{-5}=\dfrac{(1+m)^2}{(3+2m)(1-m)}$$  which is a quadratic equation in $m$

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is two lines.  Treat them separately.  First do $x+y=1$, substitute into equation 2 for two solutions.  Then do $x+y=-1$, substitute into equation 2 for two more solutions.